# How can I get many outputs using only one input?

Tags: java

I want to change decimal to binary, octagonal, hexadecimal, By setting only one input(decimal) `int i`, I want to get 3 output: binary, octal, hexadecimal.
But my problem is that when I write 'while' once to change to binary using `int i`, I can't get proper answer about next 'while' to change to octagonal using `int i`.
I thought my code about octal was wrong, but when I set another `int o`, it worked properly...I think the result of first 'while' is used as input in next 'while'.
I wonder if I use 'while' once using `int i`, then can't I use that original `int i` in next 'while'?
I want to know how to get 3 output using only one input.
For example,

| input | output |
| --- | --- |
| 2017 | b 11111100001 |
|  | o 3741 |
|  | h 7e1 |

It's my first time studying coding, so my question can be weird. Sorry:(
Code below is I made using two input.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class LA {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = scn.nextInt();
        String ab = "";
        while (i > 0) {
            ab = (i % 2) + ab;
            i /= 2;
        }
        
        System.out.println("b " + ab);
        
        int o = scn.nextInt();
        String cd = "";
        while (o > 0) {
            cd = (o % 8) + cd;
            o /=8;
        }
        System.out.println( "o " + cd);
    }
}
```

Comment: There are built in java methods to take Integers and convert them to all three of your desired outputs. Is your experiment to do that yourself without a standard library?

Answer (score 2):

You first while loop changes the value of i. At the end of this while loop i=0 so the next while loop will fail immediat.

Just keep the input in a separate variable which you don't change and copy it to i before each while loop:

```
int input = scn.nextInt();

int i= input;
while () {}

i=input;
while(i>0) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see and according to documentation.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextint.htm

You are calling `scn.nextInt()` **2** times and should be only called **1** time.
Because `scn.nextInt()` expect input from keyboard.

Save original input in another variable.
Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class LA {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int originalInput = scn.nextInt();
        int i = originalInput; // copy by value, not by reference.
        String ab = "";
        while (i > 0) {
            ab = (i % 2) + ab;
            i /= 2;
        }
        
        System.out.println("b " + ab);
        
        
        int o = originalInput; // again copy original input here.
        String cd = "";
        while (o > 0) {
            cd = (o % 8) + cd;
            o /=8;
        }
        System.out.println( "o " + cd);
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're trying to do it the hard way on purpose, but you can also use [`System.out.printf()`](https://www.journaldev.com/28692/java-printf-method) for octal and hex, and `Integer.toBinaryString(anInt)` for binary.